# Soap object on Android project return null properties [SQL 2008]

Tags: android, sql, soap

I am working on Android project. I receive informations by WebService connected to SQL 2008 (by SOAP). My SOAP object that's return from db may contains bitmaps. When bitmap in db is null, my SOAP object is 12 (property size). When bitmaps is not null, my SOAP object got 13 (property size).

And I have question: I test application on my client SQL db and SOAP object always got 13 property size. If bitmap is null or other way bitmap isn't null. What's the difference between my SQL and client SQL?